# Bracket validation python syntax question

Tags: python, algorithm

After watching a youtube tutorial on a bracket validation algorithm I understand everything besides this line of code.

```
stack[-1] == closeToOpen[c]:
```

Going through the loop until I hit a closing bracket c turns into ")"

So I'm guessing the code would statically be

```
Stack[-1] #"("  == closeToOpen[")"]:
```

Here is where I get confused because I don't see why stack[-1] which is "(" is equal to  `closeToOpen[")"]`.

Is it because  `closeToOpen[")"]` returns the value of ")" which is "("?

```
def bracketCheck(s):
    stack = []  # Open up empty stack DS
    closeToOpen = {  # Create dictionary to map closing brackets to opening brackets
        "}": "{",
        ")": "(",
        "]": "["
    }

    for c in s:  # Go through each character in string
        if c in closeToOpen:  # If the character is a closing bracket in our dictionary
            # If stack is not empty and the last character in the stack is equal to the character in the closing dictionary
            if stack and stack[-1] == closeToOpen[c]:
                stack.pop()  # Delete the last character in the stack
            else:
                return False
        else:
            stack.append(c)  # Add character to the stack

    return True if not stack else False


print(bracketCheck("[()]"))
```

Comment: close to open is a dictionary that maps closing brackets to their corresponding opening brackets.

Comment: @user1984 so closeToOpen[")"] == "(" ?

Comment: "Is it because closeToOpen[")"] returns the value of ")" which is "("?" Yes. If you aren't immediately sure of this from reading the code, then you should study the fundamentals more carefully. You will probably benefit more from a tutorial that focuses on the language syntax and how code is put together, rather than one that aims at solving practical problems.

Comment: Voting to close because there isn't an actionable question here; nobody who has the same lack of understanding could reasonably find this post with an internet search - since anyone who had any idea what to search for, wouldn't have the question.

Comment: @shayanvalaie: The `-1` index is the last element of the list (top of the stack); the `append` effectively pushes a new bracket element onto the top of the stack.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel: Vote to close as well.

Comment: Explained in my answer @shayanvalaie since it wouldn't fit in the comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you can see in the following snippet:

```
    closeToOpen = {  # Create dictionary to map closing brackets to opening brackets
        "}": "{",
        ")": "(",
        "]": "["
    }
```

`closeToOpen` is a dictionary that maps closing brackets to their corresponding opening ones.

This effectively means that `closeToOpen[")"] == "("` and when you have a "(" at the end of your stack and see a closing bracket you check whether `"(" == closeToOpen[")"]`. If it is true, you pop one element from your stack because you know that they match. If they don't match, this means that the bracket is not valid so you return False.

If you reach the end of the loop without returning False, you check if the stack is empty and return True if so. Otherwise you return False, because if there are any open brackets left in the stack, it means that they lack their closing counter parts.

Comment: Thank you for clearing that up for me. Great explanation.